# Getting scroll position with javascript?Mobile (Android 4.0.4 Webkit)

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, webkit, scroll, touch

In **Samsung S3 with default browser**, all listed native js & Jquery codes do not provide

```
$('html').scrollTop()

window.pageYOffset

document.documentElement.scrollTop

document.body.scrollTop
```

do not provide scrollposition and **returns 0**. I couldn't test many phones yet but i guess this problem might occur in other Android phones too. At least Samsungs'.

**Second problem** has occured after installing **Chrome**, got the position right but this time, Chrome does not give expected feedback to **touchmove** event. Just throws once when touch started. So added all events listed below

```
touch

touchend

touchmove

touchstart
```

**but no change**. Again only throws once at start or when i touched the screen. So it causes a delay at project workflow..

Have any idea or workaround to solve it out. Here is our test page:

http://manifakture.com/clients/zete